# Baire space which doesn't contain a dense completely metrizable subspace

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, separable-spaces, metrizability

**Let us work with separable metrizable spaces.**

It's known that if $X$ contains a dense completely metrizable subspace then $X$ is Baire.

Moreover, if we assume that $X$ embeds into any space as a Borel set ($X$ is absolutely Borel), then it contains a dense completely metrizable subspace.

What's an example of a Baire space which doesn't contain a dense completely metrizable subspace?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set

Comment: @bof Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a Bernstein set $B$ in the reals, as $B \subseteq \Bbb R$, it's separable metric. The defining property for $B$ is that it intersects $P$ for any uncountable closed subset of the reals, but also $\Bbb R\setminus P$.

There are no constructive examples of such a set, and they are proved to exist by well-ordering the reals and doing a transfinite recursion. If you believe in AC, they do exist.

Then $B$ is a Baire space (not too hard to show, e.g. use Cantor's intersection theorem) but it doesn't contain a completely metrisable subspace (as these always contain Cantor sets, and these cannot be a subset of $B$).

A nasty beast, but they do exist.

Comment: An infinite completely metrizable space can be countable, the prime example being $\{0\}\cup\{1/n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: @Jakobian not if they want to be dense in a larger space, as here.